# How can I iterate through a array filled with structures?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to learn c++ for just a week now.
I want to iterate through a array filled with structures.
This is the code that I have.

```
struct PlayerState
{
    char name[20];
    int level;
    int year;
    double health;
    int experience;
};

PlayerState States[2] = { 
    { "Mike", 10, 2017, 10.0, 1}, 
    { "Mike", 10, 2017, 10.0, 1} 
};
```

How can I using a for loop to show the output of this array?

Comment: Continue reading.

Comment: `for ( PlayerState& obj : States ){ }` If you're on C++11 and on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'll do it often, define a stream operator for your struct, then loop over them (see it live on <kbd>[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd0d89f6777debac)</kbd>):

```
#include <iostream>

struct PlayerState
{
    char name[20];
    int level;
    int year;
    double health;
    int experience;
};

std::ostream& operator<< ( std::ostream& os, const PlayerState& state )
{
    os << state.name << ": " 
       << state.level << ", " 
       << state.year<< ", " 
       << state.health << ", " 
       << state.experience;
    return os; 
}

PlayerState States[2] = { 
    { "Mike", 11, 2017, 11.0, 1}, 
    { "Mike", 10, 2015, 10.0, 1} 
};

int main()
{
    for( const auto& state : States )
    {
        std::cout << state << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    for( auto i = 0u; i < sizeof( States ) / sizeof( PlayerState ); ++i )
    {
        std::cout << States[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Can I also acces a row of this array like this: States[0[1]?

Comment: @mike-van-den-hoek: I added a traditional index-based loop at the bottom.